# Класс матрица. Перегрузка оператора /= C++

Tags: c++, linux, классы, перегрузка-операторов, g++

в перегрузке /= возникает ошибка:

В функции-члене «RealMatrix RealMatrix::operator/=(RealMatrix&)»:
/home/renata/UNIVERSITY/ProgLang/3_sem/RealMatrix/src/real_matrix.cpp:185:21: ошибка: некорректные операнды типов «float**» и «float**» для бинарной операции «operator*»

```
  185 |     Matrix = Matrix * right.Matrix;
      |              ~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |              |              |
      |              float**        float**
```

```
float** RealMatrix::operator/= (RealMatrix &right) {
    RealMatrix tmp(num_rows, num_columns);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < num_columns; ++j) {
                tmp[i][j] = Matrix[i][j];
            }
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num_columns; ++j) {
            tmp.Matrix[i][j] = right.Matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    right = right.CalculatingTheInverseMatrix();
    Matrix = Matrix * right.Matrix;
   
    return Matrix;
}
```

определение класса

```
private:
    float** Matrix;
    int num_rows;
    int num_columns;

public:

    RealMatrix() {
        num_rows = 0;
        num_columns = 0;
        Matrix = nullptr;
    }


    RealMatrix(int n_row, int n_col) {
        num_rows = n_row;
        num_columns = n_col;
        
        Matrix= (float**) new float*[num_rows];

        for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
            Matrix[i] = (float*) new float(num_columns);
    
                for (int j = 0; j < num_columns; j++) {
                    Matrix[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

    RealMatrix(const RealMatrix &M) {
        num_rows = M.num_rows;
        num_columns = M.num_columns;
        Matrix = (float**) new float*[num_rows];

        for(int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++)
            Matrix[i] = (float*) new float[num_columns];
        for(int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < num_columns; j++) {
                Matrix[i][j] = M.Matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

float* operator[] (int &index) {
        return Matrix[index];
    }
    const float* operator[](int& index) const {
    // Возвращаем константную ссылку на желаемую строку
    return Matrix[index];
    }

 float** operator/= (RealMatrix &right);
};
```

как исправить эту ошибку, если она же возникает и при использовании простого деления при перегрузке:

В функции-члене «float** RealMatrix::operator/=(RealMatrix&)»:
/home/renata/UNIVERSITY/ProgLang/3_sem/RealMatrix/src/real_matrix.cpp:188:21: ошибка: некорректные операнды типов «float**» и «float**» для бинарной операции «operator/»

```
    188 |     Matrix = Matrix / right.Matrix;
        |              ~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |              |              |
        |              float**        float**
```

Comment: Во первых, предоставленный код не содержит участка, на который ссылается ошибка. Во вторых, предоставленный код - чушь(так как модифицирует правый аргумент)

Comment: @Рената Талачева,  создание класса должно быть осмысленным. А матричный класс, который не имеет ничего, кроме простых операций, легко выполнимых с двумерными массивами , лишен смысла.  И, можно обратить внимание на то, что вряд ли кому то понадобится создать матрицу, с динамическим изменением  количеств строк и столбцов, поэтому лучше(эффективней и проще) если матричный класс не содержит  указатели на динамическую память, а содержит статические данные, в виде двумерного или одномерного массива,  контейнера ... (лучший кандидат std::valarray, но это уже о другом вопросе).